# ipython3 - no module named notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have installed ipython3 and ipython3-notebook on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

The command 'ipython3' opens up an ipython instance in the console, running Python 3.4 as expected.

However when I try to get to the browser version using

```
ipython3 notebook
```

I get an "ImportError: No module named 'notebook'"

I tried re-installing ipython3-notebook but got the message "ipython3-notebook is already the newest version."

What am I missing here?

Comment: `I have installed ipython3 and ipython3-notebook` you may want to be more specific here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
pip install jupyter
```

or

```
easy_install jupyter
```

Comment: Thanks Rando.  Installing jupyter was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pip takes the default version of the python (in my case it was python2.7).

So, I tried installing pip3 for python3,

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

and install jupyter using pip3,

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

and worked like a charm!